# Change HttpClients HTTP version to HTTP/1.0

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

im trying to use HTTP/1.0 with Apache HttpClient 4.3, but I can't find out how. In 3.x version it was done this way:

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0);
```

Thats deprecated by now. How to do it now? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/stuff");
request.setProtocolVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0);
```

Comment: only availale since version 4.3

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to adapt for servers, which don't fully support HTTP 1.1. See here: https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/issues/249